# JPA: is it possible to save a derived class in its own table whereby the referenced field is the MappedSuperclass?

Tags: hibernate, ejb, jpa-2.0

Is it possible to do the following...

I have a MappedSuperclass called Action:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Action extends EntityBase
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2604473746836781718L;

    private String event;

    public String getEvent()
    {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(String event)
    {
        this.event = event;
    }
}
```

Furthermore I have 2 classes (Entities) which derives from this class, for example GenericAction:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENERIC_ACTION")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "GAC_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "version", column = @Column(name = "GAC_VERSION")), @AttributeOverride(name = "event", column = @Column(name = "GAC_EVENT"))})
public class GenericAction extends Action
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2694061082912048881L;

    @Column(name = "GAC_PAYLOAD")
    private String payload;

    public String getPayload()
    {
        return payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(String payload)
    {
        this.payload = payload;
    }
}
```

In another Entity called Journal there is this Action attribute set:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JOURNAL")
@AttributeOverrides({@AttributeOverride(name = "id", column = @Column(name = "JRN_ID")),
        @AttributeOverride(name = "version", column = @Column(name = "JRN_VERSION"))})
public class Journal extends EntityBase
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2525323851057436815L;

    @Column(name = "JRN_ACTION")
    private Action action;
}
```

In my code I instance GenericAction and set it with Journal's setter. When Journal will be persisted it should save the content of GenericAction in its own table, but this is not going to happen. It saves the byte code of GenericAction into Journal's Action field.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got your question correctly you probably shoul consider the following

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
```

The default inheritance startegy is SINGLE_TABLE. At least JPA specification states this. I'm pretty sure that Hibernate follows JPA specification in this

Take a look here

http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/reference/en/html_single/index.html

I omitted one more thing:
you have to put @OneToOne or @ManyToOne annotaton on your action property so you have joined entities, otherwise it merely serializes the action propertty

Comment: You were right, it works with InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS. I put it on an abstract class "ActionBase" and GenericAction (and other Actions) extend this class.